# How to add a new line between LI items, so that when copied into google docs there will be an empty line between LI items

Tags: javascript, html, css, formatting, format

I currently have an unordered list with list items, however, when I paste this unordered list into google docs there is weird spacing when I try and newline the list items. As shown below, there is a lot of empty space under the LI item, (right under the blue link) when normally there should be no extra space under it (second image).

I would like to be able and achieve the second image result when copy and pasting my UL/LI list into docs. I've tried adding <br> in between LI items and other new line manipulation but nothing really seems to work. I've also attached an image of my website with the UL/LI list if that helps.

I've also attached my code but its a quite simple UL/LIST

[image: result I currently have]

[image: expected result]

[image: website UL / LI]

[image]

[image]

Comment: provide your generated html along with CSS for the list which is producing lot of white space on pasting.

Comment: This should help you put a working snippet into your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example